# How to revert to a revision by using JGIT

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jgit

I cannot revert back to a specific revision. Following is the code I am running.

After running this code, I expect to see only "Line 1" and "Line 2" in the file. But, when I open it, there are all 3 lines. I expect to get a new revision committed including content as in commit 2.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.RevertCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit;

public class JGit1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // create a clean repository
            File path = new File("c:/temp/agit/gitrepo");
            if (path.exists()) {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(path);
            }
            Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(path).call();
            System.out.println("Created a new repository at " + git.getRepository().getDirectory());

            // Create a new file and add it to the index
            File newFile = new File(path, "file1.txt");
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, "Line 1\r\n", "UTF-8", true);
            git.add().addFilepattern("file1.txt").call();
            RevCommit rev1 = git.commit().setAuthor("test", "test@test.com").setMessage("Commit Log 1").call();

            // commit some changes
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, "Line 2\r\n", "UTF-8", true);
            git.add().addFilepattern("file1.txt").call();
            RevCommit rev2 = git.commit().setAll(true).setAuthor("test", "test@test.com").setMessage("Commit Log 2").call();

            // commit some changes
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, "Line 3\r\n", "UTF-8", true);
            git.add().addFilepattern("file1.txt").call();
            RevCommit rev3 = git.commit().setAll(true).setAuthor("test", "test@test.com").setMessage("Commit Log 3").call();

            RevertCommand revertCommand = git.revert();
            // revert to revision 2
            revertCommand.include(rev2);
            RevCommit revCommit = revertCommand.call();


            // print logs
            Iterable<RevCommit> gitLog = git.log().call();
            Iterator<RevCommit> it = gitLog.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                RevCommit logMessage = it.next();
                System.out.println(logMessage.getName() + " - " + logMessage.getFullMessage());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Corrected code. A little progress. When opened file now, content is:

```
Line 1
<<<<<<< master
Line 2
Line 3
=======
>>>>>>> 54e7037 Commit Log 2
```

But, I expect

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Comment: The first few lines of code create a file. It add a different file. Probably leading to an empty commit.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the ResetCommand. Have you tried using this?

Comment: I dont want to reset. I just want to revert changes as a new commit in history. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert https://dev.to/neshaz/when-to-use-git-reset-git-revert--git-checkout-18je

Comment: Understood. Yet your code snippet is flawed. Commits that create `rev2` and `rev3` are missing the `AddCommand`. Please make sure that the intermediate steps produce the expected outcome.

Comment: `setAll(true)` takes care of adding the changes, the problem is which commit id is specified for the RevertCommand.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [RevertCommand.include()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.0.3.201809091024-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RevertCommand.html#include-org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref-) states *Include a Ref to a commit to be reverted*, so you actually need to specify the commit that should be reverted, i.e. rev3, not the commit to reset to.

What you were actually trying was to revert the changes done in commit rev2, which in this case caused a merge conflict with changes from commit rev3. This is visible via the revertComment via getUnmergedPaths()/getFailingResults() after the call.

So the following should add a 4th commit which reverts changes from rev3:

```
            RevertCommand revertCommand = git.revert();
            // revert to revision 2
            revertCommand.include(rev3);
            RevCommit revCommit = revertCommand.call();
            System.out.println("Reverted: " + revCommit);
            System.out.println("Reverted refs: " + revertCommand.getRevertedRefs());
            System.out.println("Unmerged paths: " + revertCommand.getUnmergedPaths());
            System.out.println("Failing results: " + revertCommand.getFailingResult());

            // print logs
            gitLog = git.log().call();
            for (RevCommit logMessage : gitLog) {
                System.out.println("After revert: " + logMessage.getName() + " - " + logMessage.getFullMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("File contents: " + FileUtils.readFileToString(newFile, "UTF-8"));
```